# ¿Por que el diseño de mi ventana cambia al ser llamado a la clase principal?

Tags: java, jframe

estoy haciendo un proyecto escolar usando Jframe, mi problema radica en que al llamar la ventana principal desde la clase principal se ve diferente a que cuando compilo la venta desde el mismo jFrame.
La primera imagen es de como se ve normalmente y en la segunda es como se ve mandandola a llamar desde la clase principal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que intentas explicar. Qué significa esto: "se ve diferente a que cuando compilo la venta desde el mismo jFrame"? Por otro lado si no agregas el código que muestre este proceso será imposible poder ayudarte.

Comment: Yo apuesto por el look and feel.